# Set width (or height) of element as percentage of higher ancestor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a DOM structure with three DIVs A, B & C where C is a child of B; and B is a child of A - is there a way to set the width (or height) of C to be a percentage of the width (or height) of A?

PS: jQuery is available, and any jQuery functionality can be used.

Comment: If you could be more specific about your html (post it maybe?) you will get better answers.  I think the general answer is no for css, but depending on your exact situation there may be some workaround.  I'm sure it can be done in jquery, but it's hard to say without more detail (are all 3 divs percentage widths, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, in that case, try `$('#c').height( $('#c').parent().parent().height() * pct/100 )`

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be calculated once only (no resize problems), just fetch the height of A and set the height of C accordingly.

```
var heightA = $('#divA').height();
var heightC = heightA * 0.50; // 50%
$('#divC').height(heightC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   var height = $("#A").height();
   var width = $("#A").width();
   $("#c")
   .width(width * 0.10);//10%, you can set whatever percent you need
   .height(height * 0.10);//10%, you can set whatever percent you need
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
var height_A = $('#div_A').height();
var width_A = $('#div_a').width();
$('#div_C').height(height_A*0.30); // for 30%
$('#div_C')width(width_A*0.30);  // for 30%
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A's parent has no width defined and A and B can't be width:100% for a much more lightweight and sensible CSS solution:

```
$('#divC').height( $('#divA').height() * (percentage/100) );
```

If this is for a real-world problem,  it's a bad solution. Never solve layout problems with the  JS-hammer.

The following would be ideal.

```
#parent_of_a { width:<anything>; }
#a, #b { width:100%; }
#c { width:<whatever>% };
```

CSS % width requires that an element's parent's width is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
   var aheight = $("#a").height();
   var awidth = $("#a").width();
   $("#c").width(awidth * 0.50).height(aheight * 0.50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't solve layout issues with JavaScipt, since JS can be disabled. That being said...

This code should work even if the window is resized.

```
function setDimension() {
    var containerWidth = $('#divC').parent().parent().width();
    $('#divC').width(containerWidth * 0.5);
}

$(setDimension); // do it on initial load
$(window).resize(setDimension); // do it when window is resized
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML `width` supports percentages. I don't see how you'd need to do anything special to make it work.

Comment: that width is the percentage of the parent element.  He would like to define it as a percentage of the parent's parent.

Comment: ...would setting B's width via CSS to `100%` not accomplish that goal, then? Inheritance is a powerful thing.

Comment: Matt is correct. If you *don't* want that then apparently you've got elements don't follow the usual *flow* and you should reconsider your HTML structure, or just use JavaScript.